# Set persistent cookie with Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

How can I set a cookie that is not removed when the browser is closed?

The docs of **[`res.cookie`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie)** show option parameters you can pass to the method but I haven't been able to find a configuration that makes the cookie persist after closing the browser.

```
res.cookie('name', 'spence', { expires: 0 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply set the `expires` parameter to some value in the future and the cookie will persist. I was getting hung up in the docs because what I thought I wanted was a "session cookie" but like its name implies, a session cookie only lasts for the duration of the browser *session*.

While it isn't possible to have a cookie to persist indefinitely, you can essentially do the same thing by setting the cookie to expire on some date far in the future.

```
var farFuture = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000*60*60*24*365*10)); // ~10y
res.cookie('name', 'spence', { expires: farFuture });
```

Comment: Assumed the server nees to keep the sesionid and all needed overhead for it in memory, It would be good to know if and how many memory the session cookie needs on the server in order to foresee how much memory is needed on the host. E.g. i have 100 new (not returning session) sessions per hour; what does that mean after 5 months runtime on my server side`?

Comment: This answer, while referencing the idea of a session cookie, is more about setting a cookie that persists indefinitely. Setting cookies like this doesn't inherently require storing anything in memory on the server end. For your case I'd definitely turn to using a database of some kind to store that many sessions.